# neo4j search node that begin with the letter A

Tags: neo4j

How search all nodes that begin with the letter A
How modify this code?

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name="A"
RETURN n;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~"A.*" 
RETURN n;
```

You can get all information about this here
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#_regular_expressions

Comment: This is a great answer but you should edit it to explain to OP what the regex operator is, and why this works.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Thanks for your comment. I have given reference doc where we can get all information with example.